# View permissions used by AWS for a resource?

Tags: amazon-web-services, permissions, aws-cloudformation

When building lambdas for example using cloudformation. It is easy to start allowing a little too much by allowing * on resources and eventually ending up hardening/tightening your security. Is it somehow possible to view which permissions actually are in use? And by that way, figuring out what the minimal set of permissions that is needed.

Answer (score 2):

This is a popular request. One option is to leverage [Netflix's Aardvark and RepoKid](https://medium.com/netflix-techblog/introducing-aardvark-and-repokid-53b081bf3a7e). Another is to ensure that [CloudTrail Logs](https://aws.amazon.com/cloudtrail/) are enabled and then find a way to query them (for example [using Athena](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/cloudtrail-logs.html)).

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried:

[AWS Policy Simulator](https://policysim.aws.amazon.com/home/index.jsp?#users)

I have not seen anything exactly as you described, but I believe this tool would actually in the end give you what you need and also make you more and more familiar with all of the policies in IAM.

Comment: Good suggestion. I also found this one which is quite usual: https://awspolicygen.s3.amazonaws.com/policygen.html